# javascript split regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split, delimiter

When given a string, e.g.:

```
daily (similar term)|day-to-day (similar term)|day-after-day (similar term)|every day (similar term)|nightly (similar term)|first-string (similar term)|lawful (similar term)|orderly (similar term)|rule-governed (similar term)|official (similar term)|prescribed (similar term)|regularized (similar term)|regularised (similar term)|routine (similar term)|standard (similar term)|stock (similar term)|timed (similar term)|uniform (similar term)|weak (similar term)|well-ordered (similar term)|rhythmical (related term)|rhythmic (related term)|symmetrical (related term)|symmetric (related term)|systematic (related term)|irregular (antonym)veritable|typical (similar term)standard (similar term)irregular (antonym)scheduled (similar term)usual (similar term)even|steady (similar term)steady|frequent (similar term)standing (similar term)|irregular (antonym)unconstipated|diarrheal (similar term)|diarrhoeal (similar term)|diarrhetic (similar term)|diarrhoetic (similar term)|diarrheic (similar term)|diarrhoeic (similar term)|lax (similar term)|loose (similar term)|constipated (antonym)even|symmetrical (similar term)|symmetric (similar term)normal (similar term)full-time (similar term)habitue|fixture|patron|frequentersoldierfollowersize
```

how do I create an array of synonyms, e.g.

```
var thisArr = ['daily', 'day-to-day', 'day-after-day', 'every day', 'nightly']
```

etc., but where it says 'irregular (antonym)', I don't want to include the anytonym (in this case 'irregular'). The other words (not the bracketed ones) are okay to include. But I don't want the "|" characters, or the brackets. I tried

```
var thisRegExp = /\|(.*?)\|/;
```

and I can remove the "|" to get, e.g.

```
"day-to-day (similar term)"
```

but I want to remove the bracketed things as well, and any spaces beside brackets I guess, as they would not be part of 'word pairs'. Any help much appreciated. Thanks, MediaMaker.

Comment: How about `/\s*\(.*?\)\|?/`?

Comment: what with `typical (similar term)standard (similar term)irregular (antonym)scheduled (similar term)usual (similar term)even`? there is not `|`, do you want it to match or not?

Comment: Hi Biffen, this works well for me with the split function, but on the 35th item, suddenly it has "symmetric (similar term)normal (similar term)full-time (similar term)habitue|fixture|patron|frequentersoldierfollowersize". It is unfortunate that the original string formating is not consistent, I think that's why it's doing this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
([^|()]+)(?= \(similar term|\||$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uX6mK6/2)

- `([^|()]+)` - one or more characters, but not `|`,`(`,`)` to match
  word beetween `|` to bracket
- `(?= \(similar term|\||$)` - positive lookahead for (similar term),
  or | or end of string, to match only similar words or words without
  description in brackets

to get just similar (without `(similar word)`) or not described words.

Comment: Hi m.cekiera, I got this working (sort of) with the split function. It seems to generate a term for every second array item, the alternates being what was filtered out. Or am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: @MediaMaker sorry, my miskate, this regex is for `match()` not `split()` method, with `split()` you will get reversed effect, I will try to make regex for `split()`

Comment: I added the 'g' as per your demo and used it with match and ir works great! Thanks :) Here is what I used /([^|()]+)(?= \(similar term|\||$)/g